# Get "File Save" to Populate "Open Recent" Menu

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

It's easy to populate the Open Recent menu following [the advice from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65480835/8047)

> UIDocument.open() automatically adds opened files to the "Open Recents" menu

However, File Save out of the Sandbox is different. I'm using code like this, where I move a file from inside the sandbox out:

```
let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forExporting: [urlOfFileInSandbox], asCopy: false)
topVC.present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

This is great but the file's URL doesn't show up in the "Open Recent" menu. **Is there an easy way to do this?**

(I can obtain the URL in the `UIDocumentPickerDelegate`, of course)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple. You need a `UIDocument` subclass that does nothing at all when you open a file URL

```
/// Call .open to add the fileURL to the recent menu
private class OpenRecentMenuModifier: UIDocument {

    /// no-op
    override func load(fromContents contents: Any, ofType typeName: String?) throws {
        debugPrint("Adding \(fileURL.absoluteString) to Open Recent Menu")
    }
}
```

Just call this after save to pretend that you just opened the file.